# UIViewAnimationTransitionFlip and force refresh

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have to do a flip transition between to view with uiwebview. (Flip by the time second webview load url)

My problem are that my second webview stay black till the transition was finish. (no refresh during the transition).

Is there a way to force a loading\refresh during the transition?

```
[UIView transitionWithView:mysuperview 
                  duration:0.75
                   options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
                animations:^{ 
                    [myview removeFromSuperview]; 
                } 
                completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to look into methods like `setNeedsDisplay` within the UIView class. I recommend checking out Drawing and Updating the View section of the UIView class which could be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsDisplay). Overall, views do not know when they need to refresh themselves so you will need those methods.

Comment: Still no luck.  UIWebView seem to be a bit different from other UIView.  

Anyone able to make it work?

Comment: Post the code for the webview, how is it being setup?